# creating user related user specific content

Tags: mysql, database-design

Should you create a table for each user to contain information on specific content for an account, say favorite articles, interests, ect. User defined lists that would be used to generate useful content using a tag system to define groups of content. Would i be approaching this close to right, or is there a better way. i know u should not define more than one thing in a column, but i also would want the fewest number tables too?

Comment: can you draft create table statements

Comment: i can write a MySQL query to create a table as well as write a function in php to accomplish tell the db the same, what i am trying to understand in how to structure the tables to store user preferances, or what to research.. u shouldnt store more than one thing in a single column, what if u have a list of things to store. and array that varies in number of items to store, how do u store a piece of that is as such, should i just put it in a column with spaces between the words? what should i study to better understand what i am talking about in database design

Answer (score 1):

Do *not* create a table for each user!  Create a table for each category of information you want to store.

In a relational database, a table typically represents a list of a particular type of thing which is of interest to your system.  This can be a tangible thing, like users, or an intangible thing, like interests.  The point is that each table is about a kind of thing.  The things themselves are *rows* in a table.  Every row in a table needs to have the same structure.  If you have no consistent structure for your data then you have to consider a No-SQL database instead.

For relational databases, study the rules of database normalization.  This will help you to understand how to structure your database tables.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `should` for `storing only one thing in a single column` and `define more than one thing in a column` in real world implementation. Some project stores serialised object (a group of value) into a single BLOB column. Some people separated values with comma in a single TEXT column to take advantage of full-text search after denormalisation.

You may have some insight from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564024/storing-data-in-mysql-as-json). As other experts say you might have performance issue if the value could not be search as full-text, so it would better to normalise a single table into many. However, tags list could be search as full text so it is up to you.